# Android Webview Clear Cache

Tags: android, cordova, caching, webview

I have an App developed with Cordova. This App creates PDFs and shows that in the viewer the user wants (e.g. Acrobat Reader). I've looked up the App in the "Cached Processes"-section. The more often I've created a PDF the more the number grew up in this section. Everytime I create a new PDF I delete the old one too (in my code). My question is now if there is a possibility to clear this cache for my App (maybe with Java). I've tried the webview.clearCache()-method which didn't seem to be working.
Or am I understanding this "Cached Processes"-section wrong? The thing is: If this number grows up to 700MB the phone gets really slow.